# Could anyone identify this precise surface?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-surface

Yesterday I bought [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Ikr.jpg) surface. Can anyone firstly identify what surface it is? I thought it was a pro 4 but my partner is not so sure.

Secondly, I wanted to ask what are my options for buying keyboards and pens? Will any pen integrate with this model or would it have to be a surface pen (budget is most important to me) similarly for keyboards which will integrate with this model?

Thanks a lot for the help, sorry to be asking a semi stupid question.

Comment: It claims to be model  1724 which is a Surface Pro 4. Im not an MS person so I could be wrong but I imagine it is a variant if a wacom pen. Anyway, O found a surface pen for US$45 on Amazon - https://www.amazon.com/Surface-Microsoft-Pressure-High-Fidelity-Painting/dp/B076Z7ZR55/ref=mp_s_a_1_4?keywords=surface+pro+4+pen&qid=1559995094&s=gateway&sr=8-4

Answer (score 1):

I found a relevant article online that should help. It states to use the Surface app, visit the page to register your device and it should tell you once you enter the serial number, or you can look at System Information (Press Windows+R, enter msinfo32, hit enter)

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro-surfgetstart-surfwin10/how-do-i-tell-what-surface-pro-version-do-i-have-i/74876677-0908-4799-a765-a26dab5120e8

> Use the Surface app. That will tell you. If you don't have this installed, you can get it from the Microsoft Store.
>   Visit the Microsoft Device service and repair site to register your device serial number. See Find the serial number on Surface if you are unsure where this is on your device.
>   If you are unable to get online, use the System Information app to view your system info. From Search, type system and then select System Information from the list of results.